# Given two mongodb Id's how to determine which is older

Tags: node.js, mongodb

Say we have:

```
const a = ObjectId()
const b = ObjectId()
```

can we just do  `if(a > b) {...}`

what about if they are strings?

```
  const a = String(ObjectId())
  const b = String(ObjectId())
```

should we use localComapre or if  > still sufficient to compare which is older/younger?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ObjectId` objects contain a timestamp, you might want to compare them.

```js
const a = new ObjectId()
const b = new ObjectId()

if(a.getTimestamp() > b.getTimestamp()) {...}
```

Same for string:

```js
const a = String(new ObjectId())
const b = String(new ObjectId())

if((new ObjectId(a)).getTimestamp() > (new ObjectId(b)).getTimestamp()) {...}
```